# Django Tastypie OAuth 2.0 returning Anonymous user in request.user

Tags: django, oauth, tastypie, anonymous

I followed this implementation: **[Building a True OAuth 2.0 API with Django and Tasty Pie](http://ianalexandr.com/blog/building-a-true-oauth-20-api-with-django-and-tasty-pie.html)** to bring OAuth2 Two-legged authentication to my Django app.

It works perfectly and authentication using session keys is terrific, however, I am facing some issues **retrieving the user authenticated using OAuth**, as **request.user** always **returns an Anonymous user object.**

I don't know whether I should include any other method in the **api/authentication.py**, but right now I'm using this one: https://github.com/amrox/django-tastypie-two-legged-oauth/blob/master/src/authentication.py

I guess that custom authentication is not taking care of returning the current user authenticated at all, but I'm unable to handle it myself.

This is my resource:

```
class UpdateResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    resource_name = 'updates'
    queryset = Update.objects.all()
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']        
    authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
    authentication = OAuth20Authentication()
def hydrate(self, bundle, request=None):
    print bundle.request.user
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** I can retrieve correctly the user in **GET** requests, but POST request don't seem to go through my custom authentication, so I guess it must have something to do with Django CSRF protection. :(

Comment: Did you ever find out what was going on?

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out. In my case, my Resource was simply using the wrong Authentication class, not my `OAuth20Authentication` class, which I thought was being inherited in the `Meta`.